# Data not showing in table at first click in Angular 14

Tags: angular, .net-6.0, webapi, angular14

I am using angular 14 and >net 6 web api for data fetching. I have to click twice to show data in table. though I can find my data in debugger console at first time but they does not appear in table. I am an newbie in angular.

**// My service to fetch data from .net Api**

```
baseApiUrl:string= environment.baseApiUrl;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllTags(): Observable<Tag[]>{
   var alltags=this.http.get<Tag[]>(this.baseApiUrl+'api/Tags')
    return alltags;
  }
```

**And here is my script code**

```
export class TagListComponent implements OnInit {

  tags: Tag[]=[];
  constructor(private tagService: TagsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tagService.getAllTags()
    .subscribe({
      next:(receivedTags)=>{
        console.log(receivedTags)
        this.tags=receivedTags;
      },
      error:(response)=>{
        console.log(response);
      }
    })
  }

}
```

**And Html code**

```
        
          <tr  *ngFor="let t of Tags">
            <td>{{t.tagName}}</td>
            <td>{{t.createdBy}}</td>
            <td>{{t.updatedBy}}</td>
            <td>{{t.isActive}}</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: In code behind you write a **lowercase** tags. In html a **uppercase** Tags. Typo?

Comment: Check the console. Is there any error related to NoAnimation ? You have to add that is app module.

Comment: btw, you can bind data directly to `Observable` using `async` pipe in your template. It potentially can reduce your code in view models.

Answer (score 1):

> tag.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Tag } from '../tag';

@Injectable()
export class TagService {
  mockData: Tag[] = [
    {
      tagName: 'Test',
      createdBy: 'Test',
      updatedBy: 'Test',
      isActive: true,
    },
    {
      tagName: 'Test1',
      createdBy: 'Test1',
      updatedBy: 'Test1',
      isActive: false,
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}

  public getAllTags$(): Observable<Tag[]> {
    //return this.http.get<Tag[]>(this.baseApiUrl+'api/Tags');
    return of(this.mockData);
  }
}
```

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  tags!: Tag[];

  constructor(private _tagService: TagService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._tagService.getAllTags$().subscribe((res) => {
      this.tags = res;
    });
  }
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Tag Name</th>
    <th>created By</th>
    <th>updated By</th>
    <th>isActive</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let t of tags">
      <td>{{ t.tagName }}</td>
      <td>{{ t.createdBy }}</td>
      <td>{{ t.updatedBy }}</td>
      <td>{{ t.isActive }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Working example](https://angular-ivy-4nqvqz.stackblitz.io)